# How to move the button under the logo

Tags: html, css

Im starting to learn HTML and CSS and i want to ask how can i move the button under the logo. As I said im kinda new to this soo please dont be to harsh on me haha. I tried to mess with display, justify-content and align-items, but im not sure that i'm looking at the right place.

P.S The button itself isnt made by me. I just changed it a bit so my first html+css documents would not look that bad. And course I'm not doing this commercially, just for my own satisfaction and learning.

[Site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPAk8.png)

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOu40.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use onClick event handler on img html tags. So, you don't need buttons under images. However, if you want to do it, you can use z-index css property.

```
img{
   z-index:1;
}
button{
   z-index:0;
}
```